# Getting Atmosphere transport used in Java

Tags: java, atmosphere

I'm using Atmosphere for development and I need to get the transport(websocket, long-polling etc.) through which the clients are connected to the server in my back-end.

Is there any method in `AtmosphereResource` to find out?

If not, how can I find out from the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AtmosphereResource.transport()](http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResource.html#transport%28%29) will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around a while with the methods, I found a way. Roughly, here is the answer.

```
AtmosphereResourceEvent are;

String transport = are.getResource().getRequest().getParameter("X-Atmosphere-Transport");
```

This will return a string with the transport specified in your Atmosphere Javascript `AtmosphereRequest`.